# problem with bcm43xx / b43 / b43legacy blacklisted /var/log/jockey.log

Tags: wireless, drivers, updates, blacklist

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 64bit version and I was new to drivers issues and my wireless lan won't activate from Additional drivers

and I was reported that I have to check  /var/log/jockey.log

I got these lines

```
2013-10-23 15:21:11,733 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2013-10-23 15:21:11,802 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2013-10-23 15:21:11,822 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2013-10-23 15:21:16,969 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2013-10-23 15:21:19,748 WARNING: modinfo for module wl failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module wl

2013-10-23 15:21:19,749 WARNING: /sys/module/wl/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind wl driver
2013-10-23 15:21:19,806 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
```

So - how do I fix this issue?

Comment: You should post the solution of your problem as an answer instead of in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>*moved the OP's answer from their question to this section*</sub>

1- Run this command to edit the blacklist file

```
sudo pico /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

add '#' in the beginning of the line containing bcm/bcm43/b43 etc 
save and exit

2- Run these commands

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

3- Now enable wireless from the top right of the screen, and you are done

I hope these info will help anyone